# How B-Tree works in term of serialisation?

Tags: java, database, serialization, data-structures, b-tree

In Java, I know that if you are going to build a B-Tree index on Hard Disk, you probably should use serialisation were the B-Tree structure has to be written from RAM to HD. My question is, if later I'd like to query the value of a key out of the index, is it possible to deserialise just part of the B-Tree back to RAM? Ideally, only retrieving the value of a specific key. Fetching the whole index to RAM is a bad design, at least where the B-Tree is larger than the RAM size.

If this is possible, it'd be great if someone provides some code. How DBMSs are doing this, either in Java or C?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For inspiration of how rdbms are doing it, it's probably a good idea to check the source code of the embedded Java databases: Derby, HyperSql, H2, ...

And if those databases solve your problem, I'd rather forget about implementing indices and use their product right away. Because they're embedded, there is no need to set up a server. - the rdbms code is part of the application's classpath - and the memory footprint is modest.

IF that is a possibility for you of course...

---

If the tree can easily fit into memory, I'd strongly advise to keep it there. The difference in performance will be huge. Not to mention the difficulties to keep changes in sync on disk, reorganizing, etc...

When at some point you'll need to store it, check [Externalizable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Externalizable.html) instead of the regular serialization. Serializing is notoriously slow and extensive. While Externalizable allows you to control each byte being written to disk. Not to mention the difference in performance when reading the index back into memory.

If the tree is too big to fit into memory, you'll have to use [RandomAccessFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) with some kind of memory caching. Such that often accessed items come out of memory nonetheless. But then you'll need to take updates to the index into account. You'll have to flush them to disk at some point.

So, *personally*, I'd rather *not* do this from scratch. But rather use the code that's out there. :-)

Answer (score 3):

> you probably should use serialisation were the B-Tree structure has to be written from RAM to HD

Absolutely not. Serialization is the last technique to use when implementing a disk-based B-tree. You have to be able to read individual nodes into memory, add/remove keys, change pointers, etc, and put them back. You also want the file to be readable by other languages. You should define a language-independent representation of a B-tree node. It's not difficult. You don't need anything beyond what `RandomAccessFile` provides.

Answer (score 2):

You generally split the B-tree into several "pages," each with some of they key-value pairs, etc. Then you only need to load one page into memory at a time.